# How to convert a regex data to global string php

Tags: php, regex

I have a function like below

```
function addMinus($string){

  $output = str_replace("%20", "-", $string);
  $output = str_replace(" ", "-", $output);

  return $output;

}
```

I need to use function that given above in the following function

```
function addgsk($string){

    $regex = '~\(gsk:(.*?)\)~six';
    $link = "$1";
    $link = addMinus($link);
    $output = preg_replace($regex, "<a href='$link'>(gsk:$1)</a>", $string);

   return $output;

}
```

But my problem is that `$link = addMinus($link);` do not work. The spaces do not replaced by "-". I think it is because of the data from regex.

Note: I do not get any error but the function (addMinus) do not work.

Comment: what happens if you just use the `addMinus` function on its own? Ie `echo addMinus('web site page.php');` ?

Comment: it will print `web-site-page.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be a problem with the regex, but we'd need to know the pattern of what you actually want to replace first.

Either way, right now `$link` has a value of `$1` assigned to it before the regex occurs. Tell me if this helps at all (and if not, we can figure it out from there):

```
function addgsk($string){
    $regex = '~\(gsk:(.*?)\)~six';
    $link = addMinus($string);
    $output = preg_replace($regex, '<a href="' . $link . '">(gsk:$1)</a>', $string);
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: I modified it and it works, thanks. :)

If anyone have same problem, in modification, I just use some basic functions of php i.e. `substr`, `strlen`, `trim` .

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work because you can't use a reference like `$1` as a variable which is only defined inside the replacement pattern of preg_replace or preg_replace_callback. When you write `$link = "$1";` the reference `$1` is not defined, and when you call *addMinus*, the poor function try to find spaces in this literal string: `"$1"`

A way to solve your problem is to use preg_replace_callback that allows to use a function before the replacement. See the official documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which data your want,

```
function add_minus_gsk($string) {

    return preg_replace_callback(
        '@\(gsk:([^)]++)\)@i',
        function ($matches) {
            return sprintf(
                '<a href="%s">(gsk:%s)</a>',
                str_replace(array('%20', ' '), '-', $matches[1]),
                $matches[1]
            );
        },
        $string
    );

}
```

or

```
function add_minus_gsk($string) {

    return preg_replace(
        '@\(gsk:([^)]++)\)@i',
        '<a href="$1">(gsk:$1)</a>',
        str_replace(array('%20', ' '), '-', $string)
    );

}
```

Try both.